# Select2 AJAX selected value is not appearing int he box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

### Select2 - Version 4.0.0-beta.3

I am working to upgrade my `Select2` from 3 to 4.0. I am having issue processing the ajax request with Select2. 
I have following field.

### HTML

```
<input action="load_users" id="id_pic_credits" name="pic_credits" type="hidden">
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("*[action='load_users']").select2({
        allowClear: true,
        width: '100%',
        multiple: false,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        "ajax": {
            "url": _url,
            delay: 250,
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (search, page) {
                return search
            },
            processResults: function (data, page) {
                // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
                // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
                // alter the remote JSON data
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };

            },
            cache: true

        }
    });
});
```

### HTML Result

[image]

### Server Response

```
List of dicts.

[{'id':1, 'text':'Ray of Peace'},{'id':2, 'text':'Ray of Peace2'}]
```

### HTML Result

[image]

### Problem

When i click on any of the records; I can not see if the value is actually is getting select. 
When the drop down closes; i do not see the selected value. 
The value of the field is changed in the HTML though; but I can not see the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is my understanding that you are no longer supposed to use a hidden input element to back your Select2 control. Instead, you should always use a `<select>` element.

Change your html to:

```
<select action="load_users" id="id_pic_credits" name="pic_credits"></select>
```

See the "No more hidden input tags" section on the [Select2 4.0 Announcement](http://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html) page.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jjrsre0/)

Comment: They finally took our recommendation? Way to go Select2

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm using Select2 with Aurelia and everything was working OK except there was no text for the selection. It worked earlier, then it broke as I was doing some refactoring, turns out I'd removed the view which contained the `select` and used a custom HTML element but I didn't realise Select2 required an input - I put the view back in and all worked again :)